# CMD: detect and move files deleted from source folder into another folder

Tags: cmd, backup, robocopy

I wrote a simple command using robocopy:

```
robocopy D:\Documents G:\Documents /MIR /XJ /R:0
```

It works as it should but I would like to add a Recycle Bin-like feature which would detect if a file was deleted in D:\Documents and then move it into G:\Removed rather than erase it from G:\Documents. Is there a way to do this by using CMD?

Comment: You would have to run a script to compare the files first and move non-existing files.  A point you have to consider and decide what you need to do, is that there could be filename clashes where filenames in different folders share the same name, and are being moved into a single folder.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @foxidrive. I tried to output the directory list into a file but some of the files and folders contain Chinese characters which are not rendered properly. I could probably fix this by changing the output into Unicode but the whole solution doesn't seem to me to be very reliable and I'm afraid I would end up rewriting, moving and deleting incorrect files at some point. I think I will stick with simple yet reliable Robocopy for now.